# Displaying Current Time and Date on Android Emulator with updates?

Tags: java, android-emulator

I want to find out how to show the exact time on the Android Emulator where it is updating each second. I know how to pull the time from a String using a Variable.

`String getTheTimeAndDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());`

I am using a `TextView` so when I debugg it, it shows today's date and Time (THERE ARE NO ERRORS) but it does not keeping counting in seconds. I want it to keep updating so I can see the exact current time and date refreshing. I know it has to be done in some type of for loop or something.?

This is what I currently have:

```
TextView textView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle frankyTwoToes) {
    super.onCreate(frankyTwoToes);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

    String currentTimeAndDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you create the string you have to keep updating it. PS - You can skip creating `String currentTimeAndDate`.

```
...
textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

// Infinite loop
while (true) {
   // Update time
   textView.setText(DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date()));
}
```